# Find all matching categories, there equivalent value, and only grab the values for that month? Images attached to help understand

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a budgeting spreadsheet, I nearly have it all working except one function.

Monthly Budget Sheet: http://i.imgur.com/uLJ1AfA.jpg

In this I am trying to read all data on my Transactions Sheet column B: http://i.imgur.com/0SaWEqa.jpg

if they match the Category I have in Monthly Budget B column, I grab the value from Monthly Budget column C and add them up in Transactions column D.

This is my current function: `=sumif(Transactions!B:B,A4,Transactions!C:C)`

Hopefully my pictures explain what I am talking about. My issue is I also want to filter it so it only adds the values of the ones for that month. E.g. the column 'Actual' in Monthly Budget should grab the value of Eating Out categories in Transactions ONLY IF they are in January, so the first 2 in the image but not the third.

So basically I need to add some way to modify `=sumif(Transactions!B:B,A4,Transactions!C:C)` so that it will only take entries between 01/01/2014 and 31/01/2014.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to parse the month and year into criteria in a number of ways but the decreased efficiency of the older `SUMPRODUCT` means you should abandon your full column references. Example: `=SUMPRODUCT((Transactions!$B$2:$B$999=$A4)*(MONTH(Transactions!$a$2:$a$999)=MONTH(C$1))*(YEAR(Transactions!$a$2:$a$999)=YEAR(C$1)), Transactions!$C$2:$C$999)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Month() formula

i think it would be alot easier if you add another column(B) on the transaction sheet after date called month( hide it if you like)

```
 =CONCATENATE(MONTH(A2),"-",YEAR(A2))
```

then use the SUMIFS function to add up based on 2 criteria

```
=SUMIFS(Transactions!D:D,Transactions!C:C, A4 ,Transactions!B:B, "1-2015")
```

Comment: Brilliant! Changed date to 2015 and once doing that it worked fine! Having the day is not important just the month so your solution worked great. Thank you!